# Find directory with regular expression: white spaces, command find

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I had to write a bash script that have to find the directories in the current directory and that directories must have a name that start with a letter of the alphabet [A-z]. For shell I wrote:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '[[:alpha:]]*' -type d
```

and it's ok. But in the script I wrote:

```
#! /bin/bash
files=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name '[[:alpha:]]*' -type d)
for FILE in $files; do echo 'you are in', $FILE; done;
```

But, when it finds a directory with whitespace (ex. `./New Directory`) the output is

```
./New
Directory
```

as it were 2 different directories. Why? How can i resolve this problem?

Comment: By the time `files` is set, it is too late for quoting `$FILE` to make a difference. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Answer (score 1):

This may work for you :

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '[[:alpha:]]*' -type d | sed 's/^/You are in /'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find  -maxdepth 1 -type d -regextype posix-awk  -regex ".*/[A-Z].*" -exec echo "you are in" {} \;
```